# Weird output of for loop

Tags: java

Why is the output of the following `for` loop `2 2 2`?

```
for (int i = 0, j = 2; i < 3; i++, j--) {
    System.out.print(i + j + " "); // why is this 2 2 2 ?
}
```

Comment: bcoz every time you are increasing value of i and decreasing value of j by 1...so net effect is no change in the i+j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `i + j` is evaluated as sum of integers first, use `i + "" + j` so that they are evaluated as string concatenation.

```
    for (int i = 0, j = 2; i < 3; i++, j--) {
        System.out.print(i + "" + j + " "); // gives your 02 11 20
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`i + j` is always 2, as it does integer addition. So...

1. 0 + 2 = 2
2. 1 + 1 = 2
3. 2 + 0 = 2

You can use `j + "" + i + " "`, which adds `j` to a string, instead of to a number.